# ElasticSearch (AWS): How to use another index as a query/match parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Basically I am trying to implement this [strategy](http://www.quentinsuire.com/presentations/a-news-feed-with-elasticsearch/#/23).

Sample Data:

```
PUT /newsfeed_consumer_network/consumer_network/urn:viadeo:member:me
{
"producerIds": [
    "urn:viadeo:member:ned",
    "urn:viadeo:member:john",
    "urn:viadeo:member:mary"
]
}

PUT /newsfeed/news/urn:viadeo:news:33
{
"producerId": "urn:viadeo:member:john",
"published": "2014-12-17T12:45:00.000Z",
"actor": {
    "id": "urn:viadeo:member:john",
    "objectType": "member",
    "displayName": "John"
},
"verb": "add",
"object": {
    "id": "urn:viadeo:position:10",
    "objectType": "position",
    "displayName": "Software Engineer @ Viadeo"
},
"target": {
    "id": "urn:viadeo:profile:john",
    "objectType": "profile",
    "displayName": "John's profile"
}
}
```

Sample Query:

```
POST /newsfeed/news/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "actor.id": {
                    "producerId": {
                        "index": "newsfeed_consumer_network",
                        "type": "consumer_network",
                        "id": "urn:viadeo:network:me",
                        "path": "producerIds"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"type": "query_parsing_exception",
"reason": "[match] query does not support [index]"
```

How can I use an index to support a matching query? Is there any way to implement this?

Basically I just want to use another document as the source of the matching parameter for my query. Is this even possible with ElasticSearch?

Comment: no i don't think so , i never came across such a situtation, but i want to know more if you are able to do so.

Comment: Not possible. You want inner join which is not possible with ES. Re-structure your data so that it can help with your requirement whatever that is.